# Pyspark: SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to run `pyspark` using a notebook in a conda enviroment.

```
$ which python
```

inside the enviroment 'env', returns:

```
/Users/<username>/anaconda2/envs/env/bin/p
```

ython

and outside the environment:

```
/Users/<username>/anaconda2/bin/python
```

My `.bashrc` file has:

```
export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2   
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

But still, when I run:

```
import findspark

findspark.init()
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly
```

Any ideas?

Full traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda2/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    142     try:
--> 143         py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
    144     except IndexError:

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/dx/dfb8h2h925l7vmm7y971clpw0000gn/T/ipykernel_72686/1796740182.py in <module>
      1 import findspark
      2 
----> 3 findspark.init()

~/anaconda2/envs/ai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    144     except IndexError:
    145         raise Exception(
--> 146             "Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly"
    147         )
    148     sys.path[:0] = [spark_python, py4j]

Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly
```

---

EDIT:

If I run the following in the notebook:

```
import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: In the same terminal, what does `ls -l $SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-*.zip` say?

Comment: it says: No such file or directory. but the file is there....I mean at `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip`

Comment: What's the complete message? See [Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: ls: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/python/lib/py4j-*.zip: No such file or directory

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip` output then?

Comment: `ls: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip: No such file or directory`

Comment: You say the file is there, but `ls` disagrees. How did you determine that the file exists?

Comment: by manually using go > to > folder in finder, and finding that the file is precisely there

Comment: So when you right-click the file, hold Option, and select `Copy "py4j-0.10.9-src.zip" as Pathname` (*not* `Copy`) you get the same path? Is there any chance you're in a container, VM, remote shell session, chroot or similar?

Comment: copy as pathname returns `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip`. I'm in a regular terminal, but when I run pyspark imports I'm running the notebook in a conda environment

Comment: @thatotherguy please refer to my edit

Comment: Filenames need to be exactly correct. If the file has `/libexec/` in the path, you will not be able to access the files without including this subdirectory in the path.

Comment: how do I fix .bashrc, then?

Comment: `export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/` will hopefully allow findspark.py to find py4j correctly and get you one step further.

Comment: after change, save and source. bashrc, the error persists...Should I change only the second export line in refered file lines and keep the other?

Comment: What does `ls -l $SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-*.zip` say now?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 vitorpatalano  admin  41587 May 24 01:45 /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec//python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip`

Comment: oh theres two //

Comment: Doesn't matter. Does it still say `Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly`?

Comment: yes it does say precisely that

Comment: Welp, based on https://github.com/minrk/findspark/blob/main/findspark.py and its previous versions, I'm out of ideas. You can wait for an answer, or debug this file on your system to see why `glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]` is not expanding to `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec//python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip`

Comment: thank you VERY MUCH for your help and effort. I really appreciated it.